# why the webpack 5.x did not generate the css file

Tags: css, webpack

Today I upgrade the webpack version from 4.x to 5.x, but I found the webpack 5.x did not generate some css file. this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    bg : './src/background-scripts/' ,
    content : ['./src/content-scripts/firefox-fix.js', './src/content-scripts/'] ,
    options : [
      './src/options/'
    ],
    popup : './src/popup/' ,
    'bs-lite' : './src/public/bootstrap-lite.scss'
  } ,
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/bundle') ,
    filename : '[name].js'
  } ,
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.js$/ ,
        exclude : [ /node_modules(?!(\/|\\?\\)(translation\.js|selection-widget|connect\.io|chrome-env)\1)/ ] ,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      } ,
      {
        test : /\.woff$/ ,
        loader : 'file-loader' ,
        options : {
          name : '[name].[ext]'
        }
      } ,
      {
        test : /\.html$/ ,
        loader : 'vue-html-loader'
      } , 
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test : /\.(scss)$/ ,
        use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons1: {
          name: 'commons1',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(popup|content)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
        commons2: {
          name: 'commons2',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(options|commons1)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
        commons3: {
          name: 'commons3',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(bg|commons2)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
      }
    }
  },
  plugins : [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I am using splitChunks to split the js with `commons1.js` `common2.js` `common3.js`, the should generate the `commons1.js.css` file but it did not generated actually. why did not generate the css file in the version of webpack 5.x? what should I do to make it generate the css file? I tried to tweak config like this:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'commons1.js.css'
    })
```

but it tell me that:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename commons1.js.css (chunks content and options)
```

what should I do to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace following code:

```js
new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
```

With this one:

```js
 new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].[contenthash].css",
 }),
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: it generate the css file, but did not generate the chunks common1.css file. @MAGGIx1404

Comment: replace splitchunks with this one: splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      name: false,
    }, and see it work or not